# SDL-Image: Couldn't open image, only error msg

Tags: c++, c

Game Engine Creation course work, questions about SDL, currently learning C++ SDL.
Met a question about SDL_Image, Couldn't open image.

When I run the code it closed instantly

```
bool InitSDL()
{
    //Setup SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        cout << "SDL did not initialise. Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "GEC_SDL",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
            );
        if (gWindow == NULL) 
        {
            cout << "Window was not created. Error: " << SDL_GetError();
            return false;
        }
    }

    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (gRenderer != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Renderer initialised." << endl;
        //Initialise PNG loading.
        int imageFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
        if (!(IMG_Init(imageFlags) & imageFlags))
        {
            cout << "SDL_Image could not initialise. Error: " << IMG_GetError;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            cout << "SDL_Image initialised." << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Renderer could not initialise. Error: " << SDL_GetError;
        return false;
    }

    gTexture = LoadTextureFromFile("D:/_a'Programs/School/GEC_SDL/GEC_SDL/Images/text.bmp");
    if (gTexture == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Error Messgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2MlW.png)

Tried full path: D:_a'Programs\School\GEC_SDL\GEC_SDL\Images

[Error Messgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dzes.png)

Load texture from file function

```
SDL_Texture* LoadTextureFromFile(string path)
{
    FreeTexture();

    SDL_Texture* pTexture = NULL;

    //Load the image.
    SDL_Surface* pSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
    if (pSurface != NULL)
    {
        //Create the texture from the pixels on the surface.
        pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, pSurface);
        if (pTexture == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Unable to create texture from surface. Error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }
        SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to create texture from surface. Error: " << IMG_GetError() << endl;
    }

    return pTexture;
}
```

I searched similar question in the forum and tried their ways, none of them works, please help.

Comment: The `'` in the filename is suspicious. And, if you're _not_ using something that translates `/` to `\\ ` (e.g. `cygwin`), don't you need backslashes instead of forward slashes in the filename?

Comment: @CraigEstey Forward slash `/` is perfectly fine as a path separator on Windows as well as on UNIX.

Comment: Tried: "D:\\_a\'Programs\\School\\GEC_SDL\\GEC_SDL\\Images\\text.bmp"

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, bless me :-) I assumed that a posix-like layer had to do it, but, [I just looked]  under the win32 API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file `/` is a reserved char. But, if one reads the fine print, it does [explicitly] state that `/` will be autotranslated. Is the reason that it's not more widely used in documentation is that some programs use `/` as an option argument prefix?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, yes it's `'`'s problem, I rename the folder, now it works...

PS: stupid character sets